# Three sacrifices by Pandavas

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, pandavas

When Arjuna was born, the [incorporeal voice said](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01124.htm) "...T*his mighty hero, vanquishing all the effeminate monarchs of the earth, will, with his brothers perform **three great sacrifices***."

Pandavas did Rajasuya (at Indraprastha) and Ashwamedha (after the war). Which is the third great sacrifice they performed and when they did it?

Answer (score 3):

Arjuna with his brothers made three horse-sacrifices.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14088.htm

Vyasa advices three horse sacrifices so Yudhishthira is freed from the sin of slaying his kinsmen.

> Do thou also, O great king, make the Dakshina of this sacrifice three times of what is enjoined. Let the merit of thy sacrifice increase threefold. The Brahmanas are competent for the purpose. Attaining to the merits then of three Horse-sacrifices, each with profuse presents, thou shalt be freed, O king, from the sin of having slain thy kinsmen.

Pandavas also follow his advice.

> Thus addressed by Vyasa of immeasurable intelligence, the righteous-souled Yudhishthira of great energy underwent the Diksha for performance of the Horse-sacrifice. The mighty-armed monarch then performed the great Horse-sacrifice characterised by gifts of food and presents in profusion and capable of fructifying every wish and producing every merit.

> Those best of regenerate ones, having first performed the rite called Pravargya, otherwise called Dharma, then duly went through the rite of Abhishava, O king.

Pandavas performed Ashwamedha Yagna after war.

Vyasa who can see the future told in [Adi Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01159.htm) after they escaped from Lakshagraha that in future, Pandavas would perform Rajasuya, Ashwamedha and many other sacrifices.

> 'Vaisampayana continued, 'Vyasa, the son of Satyavati, thus comforting the Pandavas, led them into the town of Ekachakra. And the master also comforted Kunti, saying, 'Live, O daughter! This son of thine, Yudhishthira, ever devoted to truth, this illustrious bull among men, h**aving by his justice conquered the whole world, will rule over all the other monarchs of the earth.** There is little doubt that, having by means of Bhima's and Arjuna's prowess **conquered the whole earth with her belt of seas, he will enjoy the sovereignty thereof.** Thy sons as well as those of Madri--mighty car-warriors
> all--will cheerfully sport as pleaseth them in their dominions. **These tigers among men will also perform various sacrifices, such as the Rajasuya and the horse-sacrifice, in which the presents unto the Brahmanas are very large**. And these thy sons **will rule their ancestral kingdom, maintaining their friends and relatives in luxury and affluence and happiness.'**

So yes, they should have performed at least three.

Comment: Thanks; I missed that while reading. But if Ashwamedha is counted as 3 sacrifices, adding Rajasuya makes it total four-- doesn't add up to the number days by the incorporeal voice. So, I was hoping there is another sacrifice done by then...

Comment: I updated my answer. Please share so other people can see it and please tell them to vote up for my answer.

Comment: Is my answer the best one?